# I need to make class with special parameters

Tags: python-3.x

How can i make class which takes func parameter on initialization, which is a callable that can be passed?
Then object of this class may be called - callable passed on init will be called with passed parameters.

```
def test_callable_obj(self):
    callable_obj = homework_lecture1.CallableInstances(lambda x: x + 8)
    self.assertEqual(callable_obj(10), 18)
```

class CallableInstances:

Comment: You did not ask a question. What did you try? what problem did you face?

Comment: @DeepSpace i edit this and i need make this exircise correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class whose `__init__` method accepts a function, and whose `__call__` simply calls that function.

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print('called func with args', args, ' and kwargs', kwargs)


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self._f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._f(*args, **kwargs)


foo = Foo(func)
foo(1, 2, c=3)
```

Outputs

```
called func with args (1, 2)  and kwargs {'c': 3}
```